# Adding google maps markers on div click

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I make google map marker appear on click? I tried by making a function and calling it on click but it doesn't work. I don't know how it really works, so I need help. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(45.159457,18.0158902);


function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(45.159457,18.0158902),
    zoom:13,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapProp);

  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });


marker.setMap(map)

}
</script>
<script>

function tagovi(){
var myCenter2=new google.maps.LatLng(45.1568915,18.0153617);
var marker2=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter2,
  });

marker2.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>   
  <body>
  <div class="b_m"><a href="#" onclick="tagovi()"><img src="slike/restorani.png"></a></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your code there are two problem  you must declare a div map and you must declare the var map  outside the initialize so you can see this var everywhere

i have edit your code properly below

var map;
         var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(45.159457,18.0158902);

```
    function initialize() {
      var mapProp = {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(45.159457,18.0158902),
        zoom:13,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapProp);

      var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter,
      });


    marker.setMap(map)

    }
    </script>
    <script>

    function tagovi(){

    var myCenter2=new google.maps.LatLng(45.1568915,18.0153617);
    var marker2=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter2,
      });

    marker2.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    </head>   
      <body>
      <div class="b_m"><a href="#" onclick="tagovi()"><img src="slike/restorani.png"></a></div>
      <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </body>

    </html>
```